# При получении данных API необходимый ключ объекта начинается на цифру

Tags: reactjs, api

Один из ключей объекта начинается на цифру - "24hVolume". Как мне получить доступ к значению этого поля.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете получить значение ключа в объекте, используя этот синтаксис.

```
let obj = {
  "24hVolume": "value",
};
    
console.log(obj["24hVolume"]);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]